# How to identify the indexes of a series of NA in a vector

Tags: r

Assuming we have a vector of values with missing values like the following:

```
test <- c(3,6,NA,7,8,NA,NA,5,8,6,NA,4,3,NA,NA,NA)
```

The objective is to identify the series of NA that have a length of 2 or less in order to apply a linear interpolation for the series tha have non-NA values at their extremities. I was able to detect the index of the end of such series with this code:

```
which.na <- which(is.na(test))

diff.which.na <- diff(which.na)

which.diff.which.na <- which(diff.which.na>1)

end.index <- which.na[which.diff.which.na]
```

result:

```
> end.index
[1]  3  7 11
```

the last NA series could be treated with a conditional statement. However I'm not able to find the index of the beginning of a NA series because I can't do the following:

```
diff.which.na <- diff(which.na,lag=-1)
```

So the expected output is:

```
beg.index= c(3,6,11)
```

and

```
end.index=c(3,7,11)
```

Any ideas?

Thank you

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can try with `rle`:

```
seq_na <- rle(is.na(test))
seq_na
#Run Length Encoding
#  lengths: int [1:8] 2 1 2 2 3 1 2 3
#  values : logi [1:8] FALSE TRUE FALSE TRUE FALSE TRUE ...
```

And look for a sequence of `TRUE` with lengths at least 2:

```
seq_na$lengths[seq_na$values]
# [1] 1 2 1 3 # there are 2 of them
```

To find the indices, you can do with `cumsum` (thanks to @Frank for the improvment!):

```
end.index <- with(seq_na, cumsum(lengths)[lengths <= 2 & values])
#[1]  3  7 11

beg.index <- end.index - with(seq_na, +(lengths==2 & values)[lengths <= 2 & values])
#[1]  3  6 11
```

Comment: thanks @Frank : yes, I meant exactly that but I was "saying" it (I was editing when you commented) in a less nice way ;-)

Comment: And now to find the index of the beginning of the series?

Comment: @Sam `with(rle(is.na(test)), cumsum(lengths)[which( lengths <= 2 & values == TRUE ) - 1] + 1)` which doesn't work if you start with a string of <= 2 NAs...

Comment: Could be simplified to `with(rle(is.na(test)), cumsum(lengths)[lengths <= 2 & values])`

Comment: Ok this is the complete solution. thx a lot for your help:



`test <- c(NA,NA,3,6,NA,7,8,NA,NA,5,8,6,NA,4,3,NA,NA,NA)


rle(is.na(test))

end.index <- with(rle(is.na(test)), cumsum(lengths)[lengths <= 2 & values])

beg.index <- with(rle(is.na(test)), cumsum(lengths)[which( lengths <= 2 & values) - 1] + 1)

if(is.na(beg.index[1])){
  beg.index <- beg.index[2:length(beg.index)]
}`  . You can add it in your answer if you wish :)

Comment: @Sam, I chose an alternative to compute `beg.index` (I edited the question)